# how to use Kubernetes DNS for pods?

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

On GKE, **kube-dns** is running on my nodes, I can see the docker containers.

I do have access to **Services** by name, which is great for all these applications where load balancing is a perfectly suitable solution, but *how would I use the DNS to access individual pods?*

I know I can look up specific pods in the API, but I need to update the `hosts` file myself, and keep watching the pod list. DNS is supposed to do that for me so how is it meant to be used within a pod?

The Kubernetes doc says the DNS info needs to be passed to the kubelet but I have no access to that on GKE that I know of, so is it just not setup that way on GKE or is there something to do to activate it?

Some of my services (zookeeper in particular) is aware of other nodes on its own, and tries to connect to them by host name (that is pod name) and that fails unless I update the `hosts` file myself. I would like to use the integrated DNS service for that.

Any guidance on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

According to the docs, the format is now:

`_my-port-name._my-port-protocol.my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`

See the related doc here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

as of this date, this is actually not possible... but it is being looked at by the Kubernetes team.

See this issue : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13552

**UPDATE**:

DNS is available for Pods since 09/2015
See PR:https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/13759

in short:

> This will give pods dns in the form of
>   `<podIP>.<namespace>.pod.<clusterSuffix>` Currently can be disabled, but
>   is either on for all pods or off.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work for me. Is it really supposed to work with kube-dns? Is the option to enable/disable it documented anywhere?

Comment: the doc is here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods  so indeed it changed a bit since that time

Comment: The second update on top seems wrong. It still says it's `podIP`…. Unfortunately that is UtterlyUseless™ (because the IP is never predictable) and UtterlyPointless™ (because if you know the IP, you can use it directly and don't need an A record).

Comment: The only thing that I found that works is that *headless* (with `clusterIP: None`) service creates the `<pod-name>.<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.<cluster-suffix>` entries (plus the `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.<cluster-suffix>` as A records for all endpoints). Which means I need two services for the StatefulSet. Took quite a bit of trial and error to find out.

Comment: I've discovered that coredns supports zone transfer feature. "dig -t AXFR cluster.local any" Unfortunately it doesn't include pods at the moment (probably it's version specific). https://github.com/coredns/coredns/pull/1259

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes statefulset support associate a service name, and define pod dns name by the service name.

Such as your create a zk daemonset, and a zk service, then the dns name of zk daemonset's first pod is zk-0.$(servicename).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local

more details see:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

**Important:** The service *must* be “[headless](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)” for this to work, that is it's `.spec.clusterIP` *must* be `None`.

Comment: this answer is wrong. it's missing the service name component in the dns name.

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes provides Stable Network IDs for all components of `StatefulSet`

Consider following example:

```yaml
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mynamespace
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  serviceName: myservice
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  # ...
```

Then you'll have following resolvable DNS entries within the k8s cluster:

- `myservice.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local` for loadbalanced access to one of `myapp` pods through the `myservice`
- `myapp-0.myservice.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local` for direct access to Pod 0 of `myapp` `StatetefulSet`
- `myapp-1.myservice.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local` for direct access to Pod 1 of `myapp` `StatetefulSet`

Documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id