# Ping pods of a statefulset via DNS

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I am setting up VerneMQ (a MQTT broker) in a cluster configuration. Therefore I am launching 4 replicas in a stateful set. Apparently VerneMQ wants to communicate with the other brokers in a cluster via DNS like this:

```
echo "Will join an existing Kubernetes cluster with discovery node at 
${kube_pod_name}.${VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_SUBDOMAIN}.${DOCKER_VERNEMQ_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local"
```

Unfortunately the logs indicate that this doesn't work:

> 14:05:56.741 [info] Application vmq_server started on node
>   'VerneMQ@broker-vernemq-0.broker-vernemq.messaging.svc.cluster.local'

`broker-vernemq-0` is the pod's name and `broker-vernemq` is the name of the statefulset. The service is configured as LoadBalancer.

**The problem:**

I connected to the pod `broker-vernemq-1` via terminal and executed `ping broker-vernemq-0` and I wondered that it is not able to resolve this hostname:

> ping: unknown host broker-vernemq-0

I was under the impression that this is supposed to work?

Comment: Have you tried to ping not pod name, but FQDN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service must be headless for kube-dns to service domain names like that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46638059